# ¿Por qué no es posible almacenar un directorio vacío en git?

Tags: git

Como dice el titulo:  ¿Por qué no es posible almacenar un directorio vacío en git?

Por ejemplo, en un repo nuevo:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ git add foo
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

El directorio vacío **foo**, no está en la lista de cambios.

Comment: Más allá de que no es respuesta a tu pregunta, se suele poner un archivo vacio, por ejemplo: .gitkeep o .hgkeep para Mercurial, para guardar directorios. En linux alcanza con `touch .gitkeep`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encontré esto en el [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) (traducido):

> Actualmente el diseño de Git solo permite el listado de archivos. Nadie lo suficientemente competente se ha preocupado de hacer los cambios necesarios para permitir la gestión de directorios vacíos.
>
> Los directorios son creados automáticamente cuando se añaden ficheros en dicho directorio. Esto quiere decir que los directorios no son registrados por sí mismos.
>
> Con el comando "git add <dir>" se añadirán los ficheros del directorio.
>
> Si es necesario tener un directorio en tus checkouts, tienes que contener al menos un fichero. .gitignore puede ayudarte en esta tarea automatizando el trabajo. Puedes dejarlo vacío o rellenarlo con los nombres de los ficheros que no quieres mostrar en el directorio.

Y [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932982/13860), elabora en la opción de **.gitignore**, y segura ese contenido:

```
 # Ignorar todo en este directorio
 *
 # Excepto este archivo
 !.gitignore
```

También es usual utilizar el fichero **.gitkeep** dentro del directorio si realmente es necesario crear el directorio y versionarlo, dentro del fichero se puede escribir brevemente por qué razón se necesita mantener el directorio versionado aunque no tenga ningún otro fichero a parte del **.gitkeep**. Esta es solo una convención, para git este fichero carece de significado especial.

Answer (score 4):

Los repositorios se usan para almacenar un historial de los cambios en los **ficheros**.

Un directorio como tal no va a tener historial de cambios, luego no tiene demasiado sentido que un repositorio almacene un directorio vacío.

Hay que tener en cuenta que los repositorios suelen crear directorios únicamente para replicar la organización de los ficheros que se suben. Es decir, un directorio únicamente sirve como medio para almacenar ficheros. Si un directorio está vacío pierde su sentido dentro del repositorio.

Comment: `Un directorio como tal no va a tener historial de cambios` -- eso no puede ser la razón... un fichero nuevo tampoco tiene historia de cambios.

Comment: Algo nuevo obviamente no va a tener cambios, pero dime qué cambios va a tener una carpeta después de 100 commits... Ninguno? Sin embargo los ficheros contenidos en la misma si pueden haber sufrido cambios y muchos. La función del repositorio no es almacenar un entorno de producción sino almacenar un historial de cambios y sincronizar cambios realizados por varias personas de forma simultánea.

Comment: Un directorio tiene metadatos, lo mismo que un archivo. Permisos, dueños, etc. Y eso tiene historia.  También un archivo de 0 bytes. Obviamente, no es posible almacenar un directorio vacío... pero dudo tu razón por eso. Por lo menos, tu razón es de filosofía, no de tecnología.  Tienes una citación que eso es de verdad la razón? Eso dijo algún autor de git?  Porque tengo mis dudas que eso es más que una especulación incompleta.

Comment: Tu diseña un repositorio que almacene cosas como el propietario de la carpeta... Lidia por supuesto con nimiedades como que el usuario no exista en todas las máquinas que se vayan a descargar el proyecto o que éste tenga un uso diferente... O que el SO sea distinto... No se tú, pero para mí no tiene mucho sentido

Comment: El punto es que git puede guardar ciertos metadatos. Por eso, no hay razón técnica obvia que no puede guardar un directorio vacío.

Comment: No es una cuestión técnica. Es simplemente que los repositorios nacieron con la idea de tener una historia de los ficheros, que es donde se almacena la información. Para tener una historia de un sistema de archivos tienes los backups

Comment: Bueno. Gracias por tu respuesta.